# How to detect if Residue failed?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

Sometimes, `Residue` can't find a solution or it doesn't exists. For example:

```
Residue[1/Sqrt[x], {x, 0}]
```

The output is:

> res(1/Sqrt[x],{x,0})

Is there a way to catch the error, to ask the output something like `FailureQ`?

If I expect the result to be a number after using `Residue`, then `NumericQ` does the job, but if the result should depend on other symbols, it's not enough.

Another idea is to use `TextString` and check if it says "Residue[" in the beginning of the string

```
StringMatchQ[TextString[output], "Residue[*"]
```

but there has to be something more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "failed", you mean that it doesn't change the result any further, you can just check to see if the result has head `Residue` like so.

```
EnforceResidue[expr_, {z_, z0_}, opts : OptionsPattern[Residue]] :=
  With[{result = Residue[expr, {z, z0}, opts]},
   Switch[result,
    _Residue,
    Failure["ResidueFailure",
     <|"MessageTemplate" -> 
       "Couldn't evaluate residue of `Expression`",
      "MessageParameters" -> <|"Expression" -> HoldForm[expr]|>|>],
    _,
    result]];
```